# How to provide autonumbering to a field in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to provide auto numbering to a field in MySQL Database?

This is like

I have fields name,number

```
name       number
--------------------
aaaa          1
bbbb          2
cccc          3
dddd          4
eeee          5
```

Now I want to remove 3rd field(i.e.,cccc)
After removing if I selected all the rows from that table
I want to get output like

```
name      number
-----------------------
aaaa        1
bbbb        2
dddd        3
eeee        4
```

Can anyone provide better solution for that?

Comment: I am almost certain that YOU DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of: why do this? It seems your number sequence is in general a primary key and that means - it has no other meaning that *number itself*. Therefore, you don't need to worry about gaps in it - and let DBMS handle that for you.

If you still want to rearrange your numbers, you can do this with:

```
UPDATE t CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) AS init SET t.number=@i:=@i+1
```

-but, really, think about this - i.e. if you really need to do that.

Comment: Thank you. I got what I want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a ranking on-the-fly while selecting

```
select name, 
       @rank := @rank + 1 as number
from your_table, (select @rank := 0) r
order by name
```

Then you don't need a `number` column in your table at all.

Comment: But I need to maintain number column in my table with modified values.

Comment: Maybe there is a better way. Can you update your question to explain what you are trying to do with that order and why you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code has a variable for the number position, 
for example $NumberPosition=3,
then

```
UPDATE table SET number=(number-1) WHERE number>$NumberPosition
```

Answer (score -1):

Set Auto increment for number you want

Check this link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: If I removed one record will it automatically reorder the number?

Comment: @user2605977, no, it will not renumber. Even if it did, the next row will be `ffff 6`. There are also problems with race conditions, like if I am simultaneously deleting row `bbbb 2`. This is not a good solution.